# ytdl-core and play-dl interruption problem

Tags: discord.js, youtube-dl, ytdl

The audio will suddenly pause when I'm halfway through playing, and it will show
`AudioPlayerError: aborted`
I have seen bug issues [here(GitHub)](https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core/issues/902) , but no one has come up with a solution until 2024

`use ytdl`

```js
const stream = ytdl(this.queue[guildID][0].url)
```

`use play-dl`

```js
const play_stream = await play.stream(this.queue[guildID][0].url, {
      discordPlayerCompatibility: true,
})
```

Both of these things will work when I use

```js
const resource = createAudioResource(play_stream.stream, {
             inputType: StreamType.WebmOpus
         });
```

Suddenly paused playback on the way
but if i try

```js
const outputStream = fs.createWriteStream('audio.mp3');
         play_stream.stream.pipe(outputStream);
         outputStream.on('finish', () => {
             console.log('The audio data has been successfully saved to the file.');
         });
```

The download will be completed quickly, which shows that it is a cache problem.

Answer (score 0):

this looks weird to me

```
discordPlayerCompatibility: true,
```

discordPlayerCompatibility is only if you use discord-player (which is it's own library) which is not needed if you use discord.js/voice

i use this instead and it should work

```
const play_stream = await play.stream(this.queue[guildID][0].url);
let resource = createAudioResource(play_stream.stream, {
    inputType: stream.type,
});
```

this might also be a problem with your audioplayer if so setting the noSubscriberBehaviour to play (this may help)

```
 const audioplayer = createAudioPlayer({
                    behaviors: {
                        noSubscriber: NoSubscriberBehavior.play,
                    }
                })
```

(you will need to change it to work with your code)

Comment: I have followed your method but still have this problem. As far as I know, things are sometimes good and sometimes bad.

Comment: this is my code 
`        const stream = await play.stream(url)
        const resource = createAudioResource(stream.stream, {
            inputType: stream.type
        });

        const player = createAudioPlayer({
            behaviors: {
                noSubscriber: NoSubscriberBehavior.Play
            }
        });

        player.play(resource);
`